# Problem in resolving pursuit curve with Simulink

Tags: kinematics, computational-physics, simulations, differential-equations

Reading [this document](https://www.hsu.edu/uploads/pages/2006-7afpursuit.pdf) I had difficulty solving a differential equation with simulink. I report the problem in case the link expires.

[image]

Given a system like the one in the figure we want to describe the trajectory that the fox will follow to capture the rabbit. The position of the rabbit is given by the parametric function $R(t)$, and the fox position is given by $F(t)= \langle x(t), y(t)\rangle$. $K$ is the ratio of the rabbit’s and the fox’s (constant) speed.
The general differential equation describing the general pursuit curve is:

$$ F'=k\lVert R'\rVert \frac{R-F}{\lVert R\rVert-\lVert R\rVert} $$

Without loss of generality, we may assume that the rabbit runs up the y-axis, and parameterize the its path by $R(t) = \langle 0,rt \rangle$ . Let the fox’s initial position be given by $F (0) = \langle c,0 \rangle$ where c is a positive constant. The vector differential equation for the fox simplifies to the system :

$$\begin{cases}
x'=- \frac{krx}{\sqrt{x^2+(rt-y)^2}} \\ 
y'=\frac{kr(rt-y)}{\sqrt{x^2+(rt-y)^2}} \end{cases}
$$

Now i tried to solve this system of equations with simulink, but the XYplot of the fox is not what I expected. This is my simulink schema.
[image]
If I understand correctly, the trajectory of the rabbit is the line I drew in red with paint. If so, shouldn't the fox's trajectory look like the green line? Why do I get the blue line instead? Does the x and the y represent the fox path ?

[image]

Sorry for this trivial / stupid question but I haven't found much on the internet...

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my simulink model was wrong.  This seems to be the correct implementation.
[image]

Sorry for the stupid question.